# Como remover uma extensão do Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, plugin, visual-studio-2010

O que é isto? Como remover/desativar esse recurso do VS2010?

O que são esses 3 pontos que aparece?

[image: SS]

[image: SS]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pelas imagens, você tem o [DevExpress CodeRush](https://www.devexpress.com/products/coderush/) instalado. Você precisa desabilitá-lo ou desinstalá-lo para não aparecer os três pontos.

Se for a versão Express precisa fazer o Menu `DevExpress` desta forma:

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>

Aí com o menu aparecendo você vai em `Unload`.

Para que ele não vote carregar terá que ir no mesmo menu e escolher `Options -> Core -> Startup -> Expert -> Load Manually`

Talvez você já esteja em modo "Expert".

Mas se quiser desinstalar, então você deve achar o instalador dele no painel de controle do Windows no mesmo local onde você desinstala qualquer outro programa. Infelizmente ele deixa alguns rastros mesmo depois de desinstalado, mas não mais estará disponível no VS.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).